# mismatch setting and preloading of polymorphic association for STI models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

[github issue link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22089)

let see we have polymorphic table

```
class DB::Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  # documentable_type, documentable_id
  belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
end

class DB::Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :document, as: :documentable

  def self.find_sti_class(type_name)
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.constantize("DB::Ticket::#{sti_type_for(type_name)}")
  end

  self.inheritance_column = :type
  self.store_full_sti_class = false

  def self.sti_name
    self.to_s.split('::').last
  end

end

class DB::Ticket::Train < DB::Ticket
end

class Ticket::Airplain < DB::Ticket
end
```

when we set association:

```
doc = Document.new
doc.documentable = DB::Ticket::Train.first! # docuementable_type will be 'DB::Ticket'
```

when we preload polymorphic association:

```
DB::Ticket.where(id: [1,2]).preload(:document).to_a
# SELECT * FROM documents WHERE documentable_id IN (1,2) AND documentable_type = 'Ticket'
```

i think its because on association.writer it uses `name` of base_class

```
module ActiveRecord
  # = Active Record Belongs To Polymorphic Association
  module Associations
    class BelongsToPolymorphicAssociation < BelongsToAssociation #:nodoc:
      ...

        def replace_keys(record)
          super
          owner[reflection.foreign_type] = record.class.base_class.name
        end

      ...
    end
  end
end
```

and on preloading it uses `sti_name` of base_class

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class Preloader
      class Association #:nodoc:
        ...

        def build_scope
          scope = klass.unscoped
          ...

          if options[:as]
            scope.where!(klass.table_name => { reflection.type => model.base_class.sti_name })
          end

          ...
        end

        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Why sql for preload generates with wrong documentable_type? 
Is this my mistake in using of STI/polymorhic or ActiveRecord bug?

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have a question?

Comment: @WesFoster, yes i have. forgot to added it. thanks :)